# Replicate ng-if for speific functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive for our AngularJS application. It would be used like this:

```
<div requires-permissions="['permission_1', ...]">
  This should only show if the user has appropriate permissions.
</div>
```

It would function much like `ng-if` in that it would remove or replace the element. Without this directive I would need to write this for each such element:

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.User.has_permissions(['permission_1', ...])">etc.</div>
```

and each controller would need a reference to the User service. I have looked through the [code for ng-if](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js) and I can't make heads or tails of the code.

I'm pretty sure I can remove the element using jqlite's remove function. How the heck can I replace it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented something similar for your needs, it calls `experimentIF`

```
export function experimentIf(ngIfDirective, experimentsManager) {
    const ngIf = ngIfDirective[0];
    const NAME = 'experimentIf';

    return {
        restrict: ngIf.restrict,
        priority: ngIf.priority + 1,
        terminal: ngIf.terminal,
        transclude: ngIf.transclude,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            const experimentName = $attr[NAME];

            $attr.ngIf = function () {
                return experimentsManager.isExperimentEnabled(experimentName);
            };
            ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

Basically, it reuses ng-if's configuration when needed and changes only the assertion part.
In my case, it was to use `experimentsManager` service.

The magic occurs when you are injecting the `ngIfDirective`.

Comment: This appears to work well. Thanks! Is the link function run on every digest cycle? That is, in your example, does changing the status fo the experimentsManager affect the experiementIf directive?

Comment: In my case experiment can't change its value on runtime, so I didn't checked it. You can use attribute.observ to check if attibuye has changed.